# Что делает функция javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var parseTpl = function(tpl, vars){
    this.rplc = function(needle, subject, where){       
        where = where.replace(needle, subject);

        return (where.indexOf(needle) != -1
                    ? arguments.callee(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])
                    : where.replace(needle, subject));
    }
    for(var index in vars){
        tpl = this.rplc('%' + index + '%', vars[index], tpl);               
    }
    return tpl;
}
```

Конкретно интересует конструкция `arguments.callee(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])`
Можно как-то дополнить функцию, чтобы в случае не нахождения подстроки в строке - вырезался шаблон %photo%

Comment: Что-то вроде этого:

for(var index in vars){
if (typeof index == 'underfined'){
//remove %index% in tpl
}
        tpl = this.rplc('%' + index + '%', vars[index], tpl);               
    }

Comment: помоему arguments.callee deprecated

Comment: @shurik, уточню:(из MDN) the 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of arguments.callee() in strict mode - 5-я версия EcmaScript запрещает использование arguments.callee() в строгом режиме. Кстати вокруг arguments.callee разгорелась не хилая дискуссия на багтрекере EcmaScript: https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263 - чувак утверждает, что зря они это сделали. В чем-то он прав.

Comment: замена? вообще задача немного другая - вырезать если нет совпадения по шаблону